# how to poll local ftp directory through ftp inbound channel adaptor?

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I am newbie to spring integration.So please pardon me if I am asking something ordinary. I do have a one simple use case. I have configured ftp inbound channel adaptor as below. Using it I am able to pull remote check files in local directory. i.e.D:/Outbound. Now I want to poll local directory i.e. i.e.D:/Outbound to add further business logic. i.e. Download a original file from remote based on check file status and move relevant check files to other directory location. How  should I do it ? Any sample quick code or reference guide/links would be appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="/ftp/ftp.properties"/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.sandbox.ftp"/>

  <!-- FTP inbound channel adapter for reading the input check files -->
  <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                                   channel="ftpInboudChannel"
                                   session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                   auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                   local-directory="D:/outBound"
                                   remote-directory="."
                                   filename-regex=".*\.chk$">
            <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" />
  </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int:channel id="ftpInboudChannel"/>

  <!--Service Activator which will intiates the download of original source file  -->
  <int:service-activator input-channel="ftpInboudChannel" ref="myPojo" method="processFile" />
  <bean id="myPojo" class="com.sandbox.ftp.CheckFileProcessor" />

  <!-- FTP inbound channel adapter for downloading the original remote files -->
  <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInboundDownload"
                                   channel="ftpInboudDownloadChannel"
                                   session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                   auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                   local-directory="D:/outBound/original"
                                   remote-directory="."
                                   filename-regex=".*\.txt$">
            <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
  </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int:channel id="ftpInboudDownloadChannel"/>


</beans>
```

Now based on Gary's comment,I have used the service activator and able to download the original source files.i.e. *.txt. Now i want to move the associated check files to the same folder once the original source file is downloaded. i.e. *.chk to D:/outBound/original. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "further business logic"?  SO doesn't recommend reference guides, but that's not really your question.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you for your prompt reply. Here, by means of "further bussiness logic",for this use case  i mean  "Download a original file from remote based on check file status and move relevant check files to other directory location."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that does is dump the file into the queue channel - I assume you got that from the sample app.

See the [spring integration reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

A simple app might do this (remove the `<queue/>` from the channel)...

```
<int:channel id="ftpInboudChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="ftpInboudChannel"
    ref="myPojo" method="processFile" />

<bean id="myPojo" class="foo.MyPojo" />

public class MyPojo {

    public void processFile(File fileToProcess) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure entirely what your use case is, but it sounds like you only want to fetch the `.txt` file when the `.chk` file is present.

An inbound channel adapter is not really appropriate for that - all it does is synchronize the local directory to the remote directory, it sounds like you need something like this, using the GET command with an outbound channel adapter...

```
<int:channel id="ftpInboudChannel"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="ftpInboudChannel" output-channel="ftpGet"
    expression="payload.name.replace('chk$', 'txt')" />

<int:ftp-outbound-gateway request-channel="ftpGet" command="get"
     ...
    replyChannel="ftpGot" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="ftpGot" ... />
```

In other words, fetch the file on-demand rather than polling for it.

You could also use the gateway to list (LS) the files and fetch those you are interested in.

Comment: @GaryThank you very much for your response. This is exactly what i want. I have updated my question further on proceedings.Could you please share your views on it.

Comment: See my edit; the [ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) has other examples of using the gateway (LS, GET, RM etc).